# RAM consumption inside a C++ program using Sqlite3 blob

Tags: c++, sqlite, blob

I'm using sqlite3 dbms inside a C++ program that I use mainly to store files as blob objects (I know that's not the best option).

Obviously I write them incrementally since they can be sometimes large (40-80MB) in order to do so I have to create first a placeholder of the blob using the binding function `sqlite3_bind_zeroblob(...)` and after that I open the blob writing and reading incrementally from and to it.

The problem I'm facing is that when i create the blob placeholder (during `sqlite3_step`) the RAM consumption of my app reaches 80-160MB for 2-3 seconds, once it has been created the RAM consumption goes back to 2-3MB at most.

I do not get why! If they created a way to write to a blob incrementally there is for sure a way to create that stupid placeholder without wasting 160MB of RAM, but I didn't find it. Have you got any suggestion?

```
sqlite3_stmt* stm = NULL;
sqlite3_blob *BLOB = NULL;

rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql.c_str(), -1, &stm, NULL);

rc = sqlite3_bind_blob(stm, 1, wpath.c_str(), wpath.size()*sizeof(wchar_t), SQLITE_STATIC);
rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stm, 2, hash.c_str(), hash.size(), SQLITE_STATIC);
rc = sqlite3_bind_zeroblob(stm, 3, size);
rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stm, 4, versione);
rc = sqlite3_bind_blob(stm, 5, last.c_str(), last.size()*sizeof(wchar_t), SQLITE_STATIC);

rc = sqlite3_step(stm);

if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
    fprintf(stderr, " This file was already present in the database!\n", rc);
    return;
}
else {
    fprintf(stdout, "Record FILE created successfully\n");
}
```

Comment: May be this is cache usage for zero write, try to set cache size to minimum?

Comment: What is the SQL query?

Comment: I modified the cache value but nothing seems to change. Anyway the sql query is the following std::string sql = "INSERT INTO FILES (PATH , HASH , DATI , VER, LAST) VALUES (?1, ?2, ?3, ?4,?5);";

Comment: You're supposed to use `sqlite3_blob_open` & friends to benefit from incremental I/O. I don't see that in your code.

Comment: I wrote it in the question, first I need to create the placeholder (3rd parameter) then I open it and write with incremental I/O, the issue is that the creation of the placeholder wastes a lot of RAM. From the documentation --> " Zeroblobs are intended to serve as placeholders for BLOBs whose content is LATER written using incremental BLOB I/O routines. A negative value for the zeroblob results in a zero-length BLOB."  Myabe you got confuse by the binding of the 5th parameter.

Comment: Can you give us a reproducing code w/o any blob bind, and including blob_open & write code? PS: when you answer comments, direct them using the '@' prefix otherwise we're not notified.

Comment: Possibly the call to `sqlite3_step` verifies that there is enough memory available for the entire blob.  This can detect an insufficient memory condition before putting effort into generating the data to go into the blob, and may help the performance if the OS needs to some memory management related swaps.

Comment: The issue is that sometimes i dont have that amount of memory available (it used to run over a board with 256MB o RAM) and this is why i write it incrementally as soon as I receive the data @1201ProgramAlarm

Comment: It is not really helpful since the waste of RAM already happened at `rc = sqlite3_step(stm);`. Just for the record you can imagine as an sqlite3_blob_open operation and a loop getting data and writing them sequentially inside the BLOB. Everything works, the only issue are the performances (that I solved with a bigger board, but still I find it annoying) @Simon Mourier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an issue reported [HERE](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Zeroblob-initialization-memory-allocation-issue-td64886.html).
And the oficial answer is:

> In order for zeroblobs to work as above (using a fixed amount of
>   memory no  matter how big they are) all zeroblobs must be at the end
>   of the row.  In  other words, the columns of the table that are
>   receiving the zeroblobs must  be the last columns in the table.  If
>   any non-zero content follows the  zeroblob, then the zeroblob is
>   expanded into a literal sequence of zero  bytes, meaning memory must
>   be allocated for the entire zeroblob.

So you need to change the order to fix it:

```
sqlite3_stmt* stm = NULL;
sqlite3_blob *BLOB = NULL;

rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql.c_str(), -1, &stm, NULL);

rc = sqlite3_bind_blob(stm, 1, wpath.c_str(), wpath.size()*sizeof(wchar_t), SQLITE_STATIC);
rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stm, 2, hash.c_str(), hash.size(), SQLITE_STATIC);
rc = sqlite3_bind_int(stm, 3, versione);
rc = sqlite3_bind_blob(stm, 4, last.c_str(), last.size()*sizeof(wchar_t), SQLITE_STATIC);
rc = sqlite3_bind_zeroblob(stm, 5, size);

rc = sqlite3_step(stm);

if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
    fprintf(stderr, " This file was already present in the database!\n", rc);
    return;
}
else {
    fprintf(stdout, "Record FILE created successfully\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew there were a explanation for that behaviour and a possible workaround!